# Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Serenity Version: 2.6.0
Edge Version: 105.0.1343.53
Edge Driver Version: 105.0.1343.53

I am getting the following error while running my selenium test cases in Edge browser.

```
Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver (The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.edge.driver system property

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.edge.driver system property
```

Note: The given driver path is correct only in serenity.properites file.

Serenity.properties:-

```
serenity.project.name=XYZ
FEATUREserenity.maintain.session=FEATURE
serenity.take.screenshots=FOR_FAILURES
webdriver.base.url=Foo
webdriver.chrome.driver=foo/boo/ChromeDriver.exe
webdriver.edge.driver=foo/boo/EdgeDriver.exe
serenity.browser.maximized=true
webdriver.driver=edge
webdriver.autodownload=false
```

The same configuration works fine in chrome but not for edge and i see no issues in the config setup above for edge. Could someone assist here?

Note: If I specify the edge driver path during cmd line then it works.[image]